# How to generate large random numbers C

Tags: c, random, rsa

I'm looking for a way to generate large random numbers on the order of 2^64 in C... (100000000 - 999999999), to use in a public key encryption algorithm (as p and q).

I do not want to generate a number smaller than 2^64 (that is, smaller than 100000000).

Is there anything that could help me to do this?

Comment: 2^64 is much greater than 999999999.

Comment: [100000000 - 999999999] is 900,000,000 different values.  These are numbers are the order of 30 bits, not 64.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

random() returns a long which on a 64bit system should be 64 bits.  If you are on a 32bit system you could do the following:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

uint64_t num;

/* add code to seed random number generator */

num = rand();
num = (num << 32) | rand();

// enforce limits of value between 100000000 and 999999999
num = (num % (999999999 - 100000000)) + 100000000;
```

Alternatively on a NIX system you could read /dev/random into your buffer:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <inttypes.h>   

int fd;
uint64_t num; 
if ((fd = open("/dev/random", O_RDONLY) == -1)
{
    /* handle error */
};
read(fd, &num, 8);
close(fd);

// enforce limits of value between 100000000 and 999999999
num = (num % (999999999 - 100000000)) + 100000000;
```

A

Comment: `rand()` is limited by `RAND_MAX` which not necessary `2^32`. And, you still need something to pass to `srand()`. `/dev/random` functionality is also available on [other platforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random).

Comment: This does not ensure the requirement "I do not want to generate number smaller than ... 100000000" is met.

Comment: Add the line `num = (num % (999999999 - 100000000)) + 100000000;` to generate a random number of the lower limit of 100000000 and the upper limit of 999999999.

Comment: Better, but now the numbers above 805933941 (2^64 -1 mod 899999999) are slightly less probable than the numbers below ;-)

Comment: On my pc `RAND_MAX` is `2^31`, not `2^32`.

Comment: Assuming smaller numbers `u32` are uniformly distributed, is such a combined  number `u64 = (u32 << 32) | u32` also?

Comment: `num = (num << 32) | rand();` is likely weak given "If you are on a 32bit", then `RAND_MAX` is likely 2^31-1 or much less.  Then `num = (num << 32) | rand();` will _always_ generate a raw `num` with some bits cleared in the same position.   `num % (999999999 - 100000000)` does help distribute that problem around yet at the cost of even greater lack of a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 10):

You could combine two 4-byte random integers to produce an 8-byte one:

```
#include <stdint.h>
...
uint64_t random = 
  (((uint64_t) rand() <<  0) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFFull) | 
  (((uint64_t) rand() << 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000ull);
```

Since `rand` returns `int`, and `sizeof(int) >= 4` on almost any modern platform, this code should work. I've added the `<< 0` to make the intent more explicit.

The masking with `0x00000000FFFFFFFF` and `0xFFFFFFFF00000000` is to prevent overlapping of the bits in the two numbers in case `sizeof(int) > 4`.

**EDIT**

Since @Banthar commented that `RAND_MAX` is not necessarily `2 ^ 32`, and I think it is guaranteed to be at least `2 ^ 16`, you could combine four 2-byte numbers just to be sure:

```
uint64_t random = 
  (((uint64_t) rand() <<  0) & 0x000000000000FFFFull) | 
  (((uint64_t) rand() << 16) & 0x00000000FFFF0000ull) | 
  (((uint64_t) rand() << 32) & 0x0000FFFF00000000ull) |
  (((uint64_t) rand() << 48) & 0xFFFF000000000000ull);
```

Comment: If you use `^` to combine the numbers instead of `|`, you don't need to worry about the masking.

Comment: Off-by-one: `RAND_MAX` is very unlikely to be `2 ^ 32`.  It might be `(2 ^ 32) - 1`.  Yet even that is uncommon.  More likely it is same as `INT_MAX` which has a common value of `(2 ^ 31) - 1` or `(2 ^ 15) - 1`. C specifies  `RAND_MAX` to be at least `(2^15) - 1`, not `2 ^ 16`.

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for a cryptographic-strength PRNG, like `openssl/rand`: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html

Comment: Or [BCryptGenRandom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375458%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows Vista and higher.

Comment: +1: using `rand()` for this is a security hole (predicting the output of `rand()` isn't terribly challenging)

Comment: http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html dead link in Aug 2018.  One of the problems with a link only answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a large number `L` out of smaller numbers (e.g. `A` & `B`). For instance, with something like  `L = (2^ n)*A + B` where ^ denotes exponentiation and `n` is some constant integer (e.g. 32). Then you code `1<<n` (bitwise left-shift) for the power-of 2 operation.

So you can make a large random number of of smaller random numbers.

Comment: what do the letters `L, n, A, and b` mean? could you explain please?

Comment: Assuming smaller numbers `u32` are uniformly distributed, is such a combined  number `u64 = (u32 << 32) | u32` also?

Comment: @this. I guess that yes, but you should ask a mathematician.

Comment: `L = (2^ n)*A + B` is a problem if the range of `B` is not [0...(2^ n)-1].  Better to use `L = (2^ n)*A ^ B` if `B` range is wider (and still a power-of-2).  Best is to `L = (max_possible_value_of_B + (type_of_L)1) *A + B`

Answer (score 3):

I know I'll probably get b____slapped by OliCharlesworth, but use rand() with a scale and offset.  It's in stdlib.h  In order to cover the whole range you should add that to another smaller rand() to fill in the gaps in the mapping.

Answer (score -1):

Or, you could use two random number generators with INDEPENDENT seeds and put their output numbers together as suggested. That depends whether you want a 64 bit number of a RNG with a period in the range of 2^64. Just don't use the default call that depends on the time, because you will get identical seeds for each generator. The right way, I just don't know ...