# Generate a random number from 0 to 10000000

Tags: c, random, numbers

How can I generate random numbers from 0 to 1000000?

I already tried the code below, but it still gives me numbers from 0 to 32767 (RAND_MAX):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int i,x;
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
        int x = rand() % 10000000 + 1;
        printf("%d\n",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: run upperbound/RAND_MAX amount of times and add them up?

Comment: RAND_MAX is usually less than 1000000 isn't it like 16000

Comment: Are you talking about this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/RAND_MAX/ ?

Comment: check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7920860/how-to-generate-large-random-numbers-c)

Comment: What is the value of `RAND_MAX`?  If it's `32767`, you won't get more than 32767 values no matter what..

Comment: just divide 1000000 through RAND_MAX and loop that amount of times and add all the found values up?

Comment: @Montaldo Adding them up will not be uniformly distributed. The sum of just two uniforms has a triangular distribution. If you add more than a handful the sum very quickly goes to a normal distribution. With 10M/32K = 305 uniforms being added, 95% of the outcomes would fall within the range 5,000,000 +/- 330,000.

Comment: @Mike Christensen  I thought 32767 different values too, but I'm now sure it is 32768.   (0 to 32767)

Comment: @chux - Yes, correct, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edit] The initial answer was for 0 to 1,000,000.  I now see it should be 0 to 10,000,000.

As `rand()` will give an answer of at least 15 bits, call `rand()` multiple times, shift by 15 and XOR the results.  Finally mod by 10,000,001.

```
unsigned long x;
x = rand();
x <<= 15;
x ^= rand();
x %= 10000001;
```

The distribution is very flat, but does introduce a very *small* bias.  After 32768*32768 iterations, each value of `x` 0 to 10,000,000 to occur *about* 107.37 times.  Instead they range from 107 to 108 times.

Combining multiple `rand()` call results with `+`, `*` or `|` will cause a significant bias in the distribution of the results.

[Edit]

`RAND_MAX` is 32767 (0x7FFF) for OP's platform.  The C spec says "value of the RAND_MAX macro shall be at least 32767".  Because RAND_MAX *may* be longer than 15 bits, it is important to use the `^` operator above rather than `|` for this code when used on other platforms.

Comment: Will using XOR make the distribution better?

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Using `^` will _maintain_ the distribution quality - do no harm.  Using `+` or `|` will make the distribution worse if RAND_MAX > 32767.

Answer (score 2):

Calculate with `% 1000001` if you want numbers between 0 and 1000000.
Also `RAND_MAX` is conly guaranteed to be at least 32767

```
int main(){
  int i, x;
  srand(time(NULL));
  for(i=0; i<10000; i++){
    x = (rand() * rand()) % 1000001;
    printf("%d\n",x);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jongware RAND_MAX is guaranteed to be 32767 - so `32767 * 32767 = 1073676289` should be sufficient

Comment: Ta, just noticed the tweak in your code that evades it. Sorry. Aren't there any side effects to multiplying? Personally, I'd rather use XOR and a shift -- Maybe I should compare these two methods.

Comment: alternatively: ( rand() + rand() + rand() + rand() ) % 100000;

Comment: @Constantin Won't you miss all prime numbers above RAND_MAX by factoring two rand() results? If my poor maths skills are right, you will not get all numbers back in the sequence.

Comment: @thst: ooh excellent! That must have been nagging me in the back in my mind (way, way back).

Comment: @Jongware There should be no noticeable side effect - most likely a strange probability distribution could happen: just like thst mentioned

Comment: @Constantin: thst is right but not for the reason you think. Using multiplication, there is no way you can get 32771.

Comment: @Jongware Yes, I'm aware of prime numbers. But you can still get 32771: imagine one rand() call equals to 19861 and the other one to 52

Comment: @Constantin: (cough-blush) okay, there is a hidden sublety there. Let's find out who falls *next* for the "obviously wrong" answer ... (I did, then decided to think it tru').

Comment: (rand() | (rand()<<15)) should be sufficient

Comment: @technosaurus  `(rand() ^ (rand()<<15))` would be better (^ vs. |).

Comment: @Jongware I'll take the shot and assert "obviously poor answer". Calling rand() twice is like 2 32768 sided dice with 32768*32768 combinations. The product modded by 1000001 comes up with distribution most uneven. The average occurrence should be ~1074, but 0 comes up 67479 times and 896370 comes up only 800 (the worst) times.

Comment: Okay, here is a math statement against using multiplication: `0` is 3 times more likely to appear than `1` as the first bit. Does that sound about right? (It's 6:30 in the morning over here....)

Comment: @chux - there is no functional difference, 0-32767 falls in the first 15 bits, so unless you have a platform where XOR bitops are faster than OR bitops(they _do_ exist), it really wouldn't be.  A `union{int x;struct{ short a:15; short b:15; short pad:2; }random; }u` would eliminate both, but needs c99 to be dependable.

Comment: @technosaurus `RAND_MAX` is 15 bits per OP's situation.  `RAND_MAX` is at _least_ 15 bits per the C spec.  Thus using `^` versus `|` deals well with the case where `RAND_MAX` is more than 15 bits.

Comment: @chux good point, it keeps from having to mask with & 0x7FFF for systems where rand() may return more than 15bits.  I think I'll compare the asm to the bitfield union to see what the compiler does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function, it will give you random number between two number (min and max) :

```
unsigned long int my_rand (unsigned long int Min, unsigned long int Max)
{
  static int first = 0;
  if (first == 0)
  {
    srand (time (NULL)); //initialize generator of random number
    first = 1;
  }
  return ((unsigned long int)(rand() * (Max+1 - Min) / RAND_MAX + Min));
}
```